# SimpleAdapter with layout and SQLite crashing on startup Android

Tags: android, listadapter, simpleadapter

Im trying to make an app in android with an list!

well im getting the data i want from my database and now im trying to put in in an listview

i tried following an tutorial and that worked.

now im building an app for myself and my app crashes on startup here is the code of my activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_stats);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stats);
        ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listShit);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> shitList =  dbTools.getAllShits();
          dbTools.getAllShits();


        if(shitList.size()!=0) {



            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( stats.this,shitList, R.id.shit_entry, new String[] { "shitId","earned"}, new int[] {R.id.shitId, R.id.earned});


            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

the logcat

```
8-11 21:29:47.718  29617-29617/jmsbrk.crappapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jmsbrk.crappapp, PID: 29617
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jmsbrk.crappapp/jmsbrk.crappapp.stats}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
            at jmsbrk.crappapp.stats.onCreate(stats.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post log cat brother!!!

Comment: will do thanks for the tip first question!

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter,  not SimpleAdapter

Comment: When trying to use the SimpleCursorAdapter i cant import it in the project

Comment: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: what you mean you cannot import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're extending ListActivity, Android by default tries to search for a Listview with id "@android:id/list". Make sure you are setting this.

A basic example would be:

```
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```